# Evaluating $\lim_{c\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left[\frac{1+c\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\right]$

Tags: calculus

The equality
$$k_a=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{ab}(c)}{\sqrt{ab}+c}\right]$$

is equal to $a$ when $c=\infty$. The condition $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ holds.

Can you explain how this works? When substituting $c=\infty$, we have:
$$k_a=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{ab}(\infty)}{\sqrt{ab}+\infty}\right]$$

what are the steps, rules, logic to go from there to  showing that $k_a=a$?

Comment: Make the substitution $c=1/d$, simplify, and then take $d=0$.

Comment: $\frac{1+c\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{\frac1c+\sqrt{ab}}{1+\frac1c\sqrt{ab}}\to\frac{\frac1\infty+\sqrt{ab}}{1+\frac1\infty\sqrt{ab}}$ and $\frac1\infty=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$\frac{1+c\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{\frac1c+\sqrt{ab}}{1+\frac1c\sqrt{ab}}
$$
And therfore :
$$\lim_{c\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left[\frac{1+c\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\right]=\lim_{c\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left[\frac{\frac1c+\sqrt{ab}}{1+\frac1c\sqrt{ab}}\right]=a
$$